# Unknown server tag YAF:Forum

Tags: .net, sitecore, yaf

I am trying to run YAF inside of Sitecore ... apparently this is not an easy thing to do. I have worked through all of my other errors, but this one seems to keep coming up... any ideas? Supposedly, there is some

this is my error, perhaps someone else has experienced this,

Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'YAF:Forum'.

Source Error:

```
Line 18:     <img src="~/images/YAFLogo.jpg" runat="server" alt="YetAnotherForum" id="imgBanner" /><br/>
Line 19:     <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Line 20:         <YAF:Forum runat="server" ID="forum"></YAF:Forum>   
Line 21:     </form>
Line 22: </body>
```

Source File: /yaf/default.aspx    Line: 20

Comment: Have you registered the YAF TagPrefix in either the ASPX/ASCX file or in the Web.config?

Comment: no, let me try that... I didn't write this code, so I didn't think coding was necessary. thought maybe there was something missing in the configuration. thank you for your help, I will let you know.